# Anime which involved a magic necklace with water element powers

Tags: story-identification, anime

I saw this anime as a kid and basically the protagonist had this water power necklace and his rival had the fire version. It was pretty funny and goofy, just wanted to remember the old times.

Comment: This is very brief can you remember anything else at all? For starters we don't know when you were a kid, roughly what year did you watch this? Can you remember any of the plot to this at all? What any of the characters looked like? What powers the necklaces gave them? If you remember anything else to add please [edit] that detail into your question!